# SQL Server transact give permisions/privileges to all tables for all databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, schema

I'm trying to give permissions to all databases to a user, but I didn't found.

I know how to do it for only one database:

```
use bd_flights
grant select on schema::dbo to USER1 WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Is there a way to do it for all the databases you have?

Thanks you,

I tried with `grant select on schema::dbo to USER1 WITH GRANT OPTION`, but this only works for the active DB I'm positioned.

Comment: sp_MSforeachdb  ....

Comment: Note: `grant select on schema::dbo to USER1` grants select permissions to USER1 on dbo schema, not on the entire database. A database might contain more than one schema. 
Also, [cross-site dupliuate](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/117759/68798)

Comment: If you really want them to be able to select in any database on the instance, some combination of the `connect any database` and `view any database` server-level permissions will do it. Be 100% sure that you want them to have those permissions not only in currently existing databases but any future ones on the instance though!